# Computer wakes up when called by ip

Tags: networking, windows-8, windows-10, sleep, wake-on-lan

I have a Z97 motherboard from ASUS (windows 10), setup to work with wake on lan in uefi and windows settings:

- In the uefi settings I enabled wake on pci express from APM settings
- in windows, device manager, network cards, it's checked to only wake on magic PACKET, not pattern (pattern is disabled)

problem is, i can wake it up by simply calling the ip address

No wake on lan packets are sent. I just do a node js script that calls the ip of the computer and it powers on the pc

I did check with the powercfg utility to see if there are any armed devices and such, only the NIC is armed (which is should be for wol to work). also, -lastwake option doesn't say anything (wake history count - 0)

Other patterns that I noticed:

- if I shutdown windows -> run script -> powers on by ip
- if I shutdown windows -> turn off PSU -> turn on PSU -> run script ->
  DOES NOT power on by ip. it DOES power on by wol (which is good)

I'm thinking if maybe there's something wrong with how windows shuts down the computer? I did try the "complete shutdown" using a shortcut for "shutdown /s /t 0" with the same result though.

just for infos, the script i'm running is this, so nothing fancy:

```
var request = require("request");

request({
    url: "http://192.168.1.9/",
    body: "",
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 3000,
}, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('done');
});
```

not sure what else i could try

Answer (score 0):

*Not directly a solution but more an in depth explanation...*

There's nothing wrong with the way Windows is shutting down your machine. That pattern can be explained due to different [System Power States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373229(v=vs.85).aspx).

You might explore the different options for [POWERCFG](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx).

For example:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg /availablesleepstates
The following sleep states are available on this system:
Standby (S3)
Hibernate
Hybrid Sleep
Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S2)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
    The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```